# I received Access Denied error when try access quicklinks.aspx in SharePoint

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint

I am trying to access /_layouts/15/quicklinks.aspx in my local SharePoint but I received the following error:

Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

How can I fix this error?

I plan to call some custom API from this location but first I need to access it.

Comment: There's no API at this location. The error is clear too, you have no permissions to connet to the site. What did you try? Have you tried actually opening a browser and navigating there? If that doesn't work, you need to ask the admin for permissions. Have you tried using eg HttpClient to GET that link? Did you forget to use Windows credentials perhaps? Which SharePoint version are you using?

Comment: The `.aspx` suffix means you use an older version. *No* version offers access to any kind of API through the page URLs though. Assuming you use at least SP 2010 you can one of the client APIs like the [Client Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537247(v=office.14)) or OData

Comment: BTW a layout page isn't supposed to be accessed directly in any case. That page is the generic template used to display a user's quicklinks, no the links themselves. If you want to retrieve a user's quicklinks, you need to get them from the user's profile.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You do not have permissions to view it because you havn't been given permission based on the account you are logged in from.

2.) It's a server error and cached in memory.  Clear cache or try opening in another browser.

Comment: How can I set permission to page in SharePoint?